# Name output from a for loop using a list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, output

I have a list of audio recordings that I am using a for loop to read in, clip, rename, and write out. I am trying to rename the clips using random numbers from an associated "master" table so that the clips can be used in a randomized blind study.

The code below works as desired with `sample(100:999,1)` in place of the code between the triple tildes (`~~~`) below (which doesn't run, but hopefully shows the desired outcome), but there is the small chance of getting duplicate clipIDs. How do I get the output of each loop iteration to be named by it's corresponding ID?

```
recording_list <- recording_summary$Original_filename # chr [1:100]
clipID_list <- recording_summary$ClipID # int [1:100]

for (i in c(recording_list)){
  wavIN <- readWave(i, from=120, to=301, units="seconds")
  writeWave(wavIN, paste0(~~~i in c(clipID_list)~~~, ".wav"))
  rm(wavIN)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I am moving along multiple variables, I tend to use an index (or name) instead. This should work for you:

```
recording_list <- recording_summary$Original_filename # chr [1:100]
clipID_list <- recording_summary$ClipID # int [1:100]

for (idx in 1:length(recording_list)){
  wavIN <- readWave(recording_list[idx], from=120, to=301, units="seconds")
  writeWave(wavIN, paste0(clipID_list[idx], ".wav"))
  rm(wavIN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-populate the list of ID/names for each iteration

```
# Generate a list of 100 unique random integers between 100 and 999
name_list = sample(100:999, 100)

# Largely the same code from your post
for (i in seq_along(recording_list)) {
  wavIN <- readWave(recording_list[i], from=120, to=301, units="seconds")
  writeWave(wavIN, paste0(name_list[i], ".wav"))
  rm(wavIN)
}

# Write list of file name and recording_list pairs for safe keeping.
cbind(recording_list, name_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution—I chose the other answer because of the useful info on the index approach, but this worked well too.